# When RaisePropertyChanged actually gets executed

Tags: c#, events, raiseevent

c# ,VS 2011 ,Silverlight 4.

when RaisePropertyChanged("...")  actually gets executed   A, B, or C  (see below)

if I have a C# method

```
public void OnSave()
{
   RaisePropertyChanged("my property");

     (A)   is it executed here or (B) after the method is finished (or (C) we cannot know)?

   bla,bla,bla (more code)





}
```

or (B) Here?

Comment: You coul try putting some breakpoints. One in bla bla and one in your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Well the implementation of `RaisePropertyChanged` not withstanding, the execute call will be made immediately before any other code in the block (or option A as you have described.)

...

```
public void OnSave()
{
    RaisePropertyChanged("my property");

    //.. All following code gets executed AFTER RaisePropertyChanged returns execution
}
```

The reason I say the implementation not withstanding is because if the method utilizes asynchronous code then it is possible that the return will happen immediately and that the actual work invoked by the method could be completed after other code in the block following `RaisePropertyChanged`.. I hope that isn't too much information.